# Attachments category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to use get_posts() and get only attachments that are in X category. I think ability to set attachment category is allowed by installing Enhanced Media Library plugin.

```
$args = array(
'category' => 'My category',
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'tax_query' => array( 
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'media_category',
        'terms' => array( 'cards' )
    )
)
);
```

I have tried many things with category but know I have no idea...

Comment: You are closing the array with a `)` after `'My category'` - typo or error?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this code if your passing a category name then we need to use 'category_name' => 'categoryname' if category id need to be passed then 'category' => 121.

```
 $args = array(
    'category_name' => 'X-category',
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. I'have tried that - with category_name and category